# PHP DOMDocument is not working

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am studying parsing `HTML` on `PHP` and I am using `DOM` for this.
I write this code inside my `php` file:

```
<?php  
$site = new DOMDocument();
$div = $site->createElement("div");

$class = $site->createAttribute("class");
$class->nodeValue = "wrapper";

$div->appendChild($class);
$site->appendChild($div);
$html = $site->saveHTML();

echo $html;
?>
```

And when I run this on the browser and view the page source, only this code comes out:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

I don't know why it is not showing the whole `html` document that supposedly have to be. I am using `XAMPP v3.2.1`.
Please tell me where did I gone wrong with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing the whole HTML you created. A `div` node with a `wrapper` class attribute.
See [the example in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php). There the `html`, `head`, etc. nodes are explicitly created.

Answer (score 0):

PHP only adds missing `DOCTYPE`, `html` and `body` elements when loading HTML, not when saving.

Adding `$site->loadHTML($site->saveHTML());` before `$html = $site->saveHTML();` will demonstrate this.